# Kill a child-script when it emits a certain string

Tags: bash, process, terminal, kill

I have the following setup:

```
#!/bin/bash
# call.sh

voip_binary $1
```

Now when I a certain event happens (when I hang up), then the `voip_binary` emits a certain string: `... [DISCONNCTD] ...`
However, the script does not stop, but continues running. Now as soon as `DISCONNCTD` is discovered in the output, I want to kill the script.

So I could do the following, to get the relevant output:

```
voip_binary $1 | grep DISCONNCTD
```

Even though I now only get relevant output from the binary, I still don't know how to kill it, as soon as a line is emitted.

Comment: Are you using trap (and sometimes traping the trap also helps - as well?). If yes, you can SIG xx it when you see the value is returned as DISCNNCTD and kill it with either -15 or -9 signals.

Comment: @ArunSangal, my knowledge is limited and `SIG xx` don't mean much. If you provide an answer that works, I will happily accept it.

Comment: See: kill -l, it'll list all the signals (with name and their number) a user can send to kill it. for ex: kill -9 12345 (to kill a process whose PID is 12345).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
voip_binary $1 | grep 'DISCONNCTD' | while read line; do
    pkill 'voip_binary'
done
```

Assuming `voip_binary` outputs your string without buffering.

Comment: Shouldn't we use "until" than while? I see it going in infinite loop with while (until we receive the desired DISCNNCTD string by voip_binary)

Comment: @ArunSangal The loop will stop when there is no more output produced by `voip_binary`. It's because `read` will return false on EOF.

Comment: Actually I want to quit when the line  _contains_ `DISCONNCTD`. Is there a way to force-quit the `voip_binary` since I want to make sure that it exits.

Comment: This seems to stop the loop, but not the script, since the call is being made, even if I abort the script in a early stage

Comment: @Besi Edited the answer. There should be only one instance of `voip_binary` in the system though, otherwise every instance will be killed.